# How to use axios with React to make AJAX requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

Attempting to make an AJAX request with axios and display the data in React component. Getting an error saying map is not a function, and 404 on the GET request. The POST request works great. Tested in Postman and the GET request works if `http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos`...can get the data to display in the console, but not in my CommentBox component. What am I doing wrong?

```
//COMMENTBOX COMPONENT

import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Rater from 'react-rater';
import './comment-styles.scss';

export class CommentBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            reviews: []
        }
        this.addReview = this.addReview.bind(this);
    };


    addReview() {    /*Post Request*/
        Axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/reviews',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({ reviews: response.data.reviews })      
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/reviews') /*Get Request*/
        .then(reviews => {
            this.setState({ reviews: reviews.data })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };



    render() {
        return (
            <div id="commentWrapper">
                <div className="commentHeader">
                    <h5>Leave a Rating!</h5>
                    <Rater style={{fontSize: '35px'}} />
                    <button id="submitRatingBtn" type="submit">Submit</button>

                    <form action="/breakfast-tacos" method="POST">
                        <textarea className="reviewTextBox" maxLength="250" placeholder="Write a review..." name="reviews"></textarea>
                        <button id="submitReviewBtn" type="submit" onClick={this.addReview}>Submit</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className="reviews">
                    <span className="user">
                        <h6>username:</h6>
                    </span>
                    <span className="text">
                        {this.state.reviews.map((review, text) => {  /*Where I want to display the data*/
                            return (
                                <p key={text}>
                                    {review}
                                </p>
                            )
                        })}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

```
//EXPRESS SERVER

require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const cors  = require('cors');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dbUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    
    // CHECK FOR CONNECTION TO DATABASE ERRORS, VERIFY DATABASE CONNECTION
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Database connected successfully!`);


    //GLOBAL DATABASE VARIABLES
    const db = client.db('recipedb');
    const dbCollection = db.collection('breakfast-tacos');

    
    //MIDDLEWARES
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));
  

    //POST OR CREATE ROUTES
    app.post('/breakfast-tacos', (req, res) => {
        dbCollection.insertOne(req.body)
        .then(results => {
            console.log('1 document inserted...');
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });

    //GET OR READ ROUTES
    app.get('/breakfast-tacos/', (req, res) => {
        dbCollection.find().toArray()
        .then(results => {
           res.send({ reviews: results });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    });
});

//SERVER
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

```
// MAIN APP COMPONENT
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './home.js';
import { Breakfast } from './breakfast.js';
import { LunchDinner } from './lunch-dinner.js';
import { Sides } from './sides.js';
import { Desserts } from './desserts.js';
import { Snacks } from './snacks.js';
import { Misc } from './misc.js';
import { About } from './about.js';




class App extends React.Component {

    
    componentDidMount() {
        Axios({                    /*This GET request shows an array of data in the console*/
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.reviews);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))  
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/breakfast" exact component={Breakfast} />
                        <Route path="/lunch-dinner" exact component={LunchDinner} />
                        <Route path="/sides" exact component={Sides} />
                        <Route path="/desserts" exact component={Desserts} />
                        <Route path="/snacks" exact component={Snacks} />
                        <Route path="/misc" exact component={Misc} />
                        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
// ERRORS

/*Error which indicates something wrong with the url*/
/*UPDATE: I removed "reviews" after testing in Postman and no longer getting 404 error, now getting map is not a function error*/
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:8080/breakfast-tacos/reviews 404 (Not Found) 

/*How the data is being displayed in the console*/
18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {_id: "600f6f2510e2f91da0a0b4da", reviews: "Testing 1"}1: {_id: "600f6fb410e2f91da0a0b4db", reviews: "Testing 1"}2: {_id: "6010e787ea6c5c1fb43f471d", reviews: "Testing 2"}3: {_id: "6010ee90ea6c5c1fb43f471e", reviews: "Test 3"}4: {_id: "6010fb2ec91e161344cacf39"}5: {_id: "6010fb33c91e161344cacf3a"}6: {_id: "6010fb42c91e161344cacf3b"}7: {_id: "6010fb51c91e161344cacf3c", reviews: "TESTING"}8: {_id: "6010fb5dc91e161344cacf3d"}9: {_id: "6010fb6bc91e161344cacf3e"}10: {_id: "6010fbe9c91e161344cacf3f"}11: {_id: "6010fc0cc91e161344cacf40"}12: {_id: "6010fc0dc91e161344cacf41"}13: {_id: "6010fc0dc91e161344cacf42"}14: {_id: "6010fc0ec91e161344cacf43"}15: {_id: "6010fc12c91e161344cacf44"}16: {_id: "6010fc785969750b0875580d", reviews: "fehafasdfasd"}17: {_id: "60120812fc750a0830ca1052", reviews: "does this work"}length: 18__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: My advice is that you try to make this post a little more readable. Right now is just a wall of text that no one wants to read.

Comment: After testing the url in postman, removing the "reviews" part of the url fixes the 404 issue. Still working on the map is not a function issue.

Comment: Can you give an API response example?

Comment: for the map error, check that the array has a length greater than 0 before accessing it.
<div>{!!this.state.reviews.length && this.state.reviews.map(a => ('do your thing'))}</>